# Total columns that use the same variable as input in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've managed to extract the data from an sql database (using a stored procedure) and show it in Table Datums. What I would like to do is have a column total for each column, but they are created using the same variable (in a loop) so I am confused as to how to do this.

```
date            AVL RSU TOW BAD DEL SUP CLA SG  RV  TEN
2016-12-08      16   2  5   1   2   3   1   1   1    0
2016-12-09      17   2  6   1   2   3   1   1   1    0
//more data will be in here, but for now, you get the picture
Total           32   4  11  2   4   6   2   2   2    0
```

my VIEW code that creates this looks like this

```
<table>

<tr>
    <td>date</td>
    <td>avl</td>
    <td>rsu</td>
    <td>tow</td>
    <td>bad</td>
    <td>del</td>
    <td>sup</td>
    <td>cla</td>
    <td>sg</td>
    <td>rv</td>
    <td>ten</td>
</tr>

@foreach (var itemgroup in Model.GroupBy(item => item.date))
{
   <tr>
        <td>@itemgroup.Key.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</td>
        @foreach (var item in itemgroup)
        {
        string style = @item.Column2 <= 0 ? "color:Red" : null;
        <td style="@style">@item.Column2</td>
        }
    </tr>
}
```

Can anyone advise please ?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a property called `code` in each item. Since your table headers are hardcoded, I'm assuming these are the only `code`s available. So in the same order as the headers, get the total for a `code`.

```
<tr>
     <td>Total</td>
     <td>@Model.Where(item => item.code == "AVL").Sum(a => a.Column2)</td>
     <td>@Model.Where(item => item.code == "RSU").Sum(a => a.Column2)</td>
     // And so on ....
</tr>
```

But it would be better to have all this logic in the `controller` and get the ready-made data to `View`.

Comment: HI @adiga, I'm just getting 0 when I try this code outside of of FOREACH loop`    <tr>
        <td>Total</td>
        <td>@Model.Where(item => item.code == "AVL").Sum(a => a.Column2)</td>
    </tr>
</table>`

Comment: Hi, it's defiantly AVL

Comment: @GeraldOakham Then you're doing something else wrong. Check this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/mAaYdN

Comment: I think its because my data is stored in an array

Comment: figured it out, it was because the out is not "AVL", but  "AVL         "...d'Oh

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do this on the server instead of in the view. Define a new class representing a row of data `Row` (choose a more appropriate name). Then create a view model class.

```
public class Row
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int AVL { get; set; }
    public int RSU { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class TableViewModel
{
    public List<Row> DataRows { get; set; }
    public Row TotalRow { get; set; }
}
```

You accumulate and group the rows as you do in the view then compute the TotalRow. Since these Rows are in a List you can use Linq aggregate functions.

```
totalRow.AVL = rows.Sum(r => r.AVL)
totalRow.RSU = rows.Sum(r => r.RSU)
```

This extracts all computation code from the view where it doesn't belong.

```
@model TableViewModel

<table>
@foreach(var row in Model.DataRows)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@row.Date</td>
        <td>@row.AVL</td>
        <td>@row.RSU</td>
    </tr>
}
    <tr>
        <td>@Model.TotalRow.Date</td>
        <td>@Model.TotalRow.AVL</td>
        <td>@Model.TotalRow.RSU</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```